# C# checking if cell border exist

Tags: c#, excel, range, border

I'm currently doing a small project with C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and I'm kinda stuck.

What I'm trying to do is creating a method which takes a Range and then returns true or falsed based on if there is a border at the bottom edge of the range.

```
private bool BottomEdgeHasBorder(string range)
{
if (has border at bottom edge of range)
return true;
else
return false;
}
```

I have searched alot for this issue but all I can find are questions about adding a border. I just want to check if there is a border.

I have tried

```
Excel.Range range = ExcelWorksheet.get_Range(range, Type.Missing);
if (range.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom] == Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous)
return true;
```

Greatful for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue.  To compare a border's linestyle against the linestyle enum append GetHashCode() to the linestyle enum to get the integer equivalent:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range("AK59");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Borders borders = range.Borders;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Border borderTop = borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Border borderLeft = borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Border borderBottom = borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Border borderRight = borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight];

if (borderBottom.LineStyle == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous.GetHashCode())
{
    Console.WriteLine("We have a bottom border line");
}
if (borderRight.LineStyle == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble.GetHashCode())
{
    Console.WriteLine("We have a double line on the right border");
}
if (borderRight.LineStyle != Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone.GetHashCode())
{
    Console.WriteLine("yeah we have some type of border on the right");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to get the LineStyle property for your comparison.  I'm a little rusty on C# syntax, but I think this is what you need to use.

range.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle

Comment: Hey! I just tried if (WorkingRangeCells.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle == Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous) but I got an exception thrown "An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle'"

Comment: Thats the same error I get all the time. Ive tried countless of ways but I still get that same error. I tried comparing the border of the range sent in as an argument with a border on a range I know has a line. Still get the same thing

Comment: Try casting the Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous as an int. If that doesn't work then you need to figure out what value is equal to xlContinuous. I would check the MSDN site for the value.

Comment: I entered

    WorkingRangeCells.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle
into Console.WriteLine(); and then compared it to the excel sheet. A normal line has the value 1 and if there is no line you get the value -4142.

So just compare them in a statement to an int.

Comment: Value wasnt available at MSDN. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Here is a technet site I found, which appears to match the findings that you have. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692886.aspx My next suggestion was going to be testing an playing with it, so you are right on track.  Please remember to mark the question as answered if this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool BottomEdgeHasBorder(Range cell)
{
      return cell.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle != (int)XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
}
```